# Imprimir objeto desde un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto, print

Al intentar imprimir la lista de objetos me da el error de java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public Productos(int id, int precio, String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

 @Override
    public String toString(){
        String a= "Producto: "+nombre+" ID: "+id+" Precio: "+precio;
        return a;                   
    }
```

}

A pesar de tener el método toString, no cambia el error, ni tampoco netbeans reconoce con la autocompletación los getters, por lo que más de algo tengo mal, tampoco es un tema de try-catch, ya que solo debería tomar valores ya agregados e imprimirlos

```
private Productos Productos;
private ArrayList<Productos> productos = new ArrayList<>();

public void newProducto(){
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del producto");
    String nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese precio del producto");
    int precio=sc.nextInt();
    int id = productos.size()+1;
    new Productos(id, precio, nombre);
    productos.add(Productos);
}
public void mostrarProductos(){
   for(int i=0; i<productos.size();i++){
       System.out.println(productos.get(i).toString());

   }
}
```

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: También te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a en el método toString a cambiar las variables por los métodos que las devuelven.

```
String a= "Producto: "+getNombre()+" ID: "+getId()+" Precio: "+getPrecio();
```

Y si no pues almacena los valores en variables dentro del método(Aunque no serviría de nada y sería añadir líneas incensarías).

```
String nombre = getNombre();
```

Comment: por favor deja la corrección, este es el modo de presentar código

Answer (score 0):

Después leer más logré encontrar el error, era la forma en la cual se estaba guardando el objeto.

En vez de ser

```
new Productos(id, precio, nombre);
productos.add(Productos);
```

debió ser

```
Productos p = new Productos(id, precio, nombre);
productos.add(p);
```

Comment: será la forma en que haces la instanciación

Comment: @Juampa57 Productos no es un objeto, debería de fallar en tiempo de compilación en vez de dar NPE, por ello sería bueno que agregaras el mensaje exacto de tu excepción.

Comment: Sep, estaba mal instanciado, pero al corregirlo de esa manera se arreglo el problema

Comment: @RuslanLópez "Productos" no es lo mismo que "productos", de todas formas al hacer el cambio que está escrito más arriba el código funcionó sin problemas

Comment: @Juampa57 no podría decirlo, ya que nunca compartiste el mensaje de error